# Whats the correct way to convert this Objective-C method to Java for Android?

Tags: java, android, regex

Here is my original method:

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)address 
{
    NSString *emailRegEx = @"[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:address];
}
```

Here's what I've come up with. Is this correct?

```
private boolean Validate(String email) 
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    if(matcher.matches())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to look alright with me, although I would like to point out some differences you should make when using Java.

```
// use a pattern as a constant instead, using the Java naming conventions (all uppercase and underscores)
private static final String MAIL_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?";

// lower case method identifier, does not use field so declare static
private static boolean validate(final String email) 
{
    // matches already returns a boolean, you can use matches directly on a string (shorthand notation)
    return email.matches(MAIL_PATTERN);
}
```

Comment: PS I won't go into the overly complex regexp - it seems to work, but you should try and use other methods of testing an email address - overly complex regexps are a nightmare to read and maintain.